# FPDF Generar una pagina por cada fila de la BD

Tags: php, fpdf

tengo ya mi codigo con FPDF para generar la hoja en el documento PDF. Ahora bien , me gustaría implementar un bucle que en el mismo fichero PDF por cada fila de la BD me genere una página en el documento.

Creo que habría que generar un función que llamase al código que tiene el FPDF desde el AddPage().

¿Alguna vez habéis hecho algo parecido?¿Me podéis orientar?

Imaginaros que la BD de datos contiene los siguientes datos:

> Alimento | Caducidad
>   Queso    | 1 mes
>   Yogur    | 15 días
>   Pollo    | 3 días

Lo que quiero es que el PDF que genere FPD tenga 3 paginas, una por cada fila de la BD.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola wiki, deberías añadir la parte del código relativa a lo que se pregunta, junto a una descripción del resultado que obtienes, y que es lo que quieres obtener. de ese modo podremos ayudarte mejor. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que generar una función como decía, os dejo el código, espero que os sirva:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

require('./fpdf181/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
var $widths;
var $aligns;

function SetWidths($w)
{
    $this->widths=$w;
}

function SetAligns($a)
{
    $this->aligns=$a;
}

function Row($data)
{
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    $h=8*$nb;
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
        $this->MultiCell($w,8,$data[$i],0,$a);
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
    }
    $this->Ln($h);
}

function CheckPageBreak($h)
{
    if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
}

function NbLines($w,$txt)
{
    $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb=strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 and $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep=-1;
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l=0;
    $nl=1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        $c=$s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            $i++;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep=$i;
        $l+=$cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            }
            else
                $i=$sep+1;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
}

    }


//**RECOGIDA DE DATOS
//-------------------

include"./conectar.php";
$enlace= conectarse();

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");


$consulta = "SELECT * FROM producto";

$result=mysql_query($consulta,$enlace);
$number = mysql_numrows($result);

$alimento = "";
$caducidad= "";

$i=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $alimento[$i] = $row["alimento"];
    $caducidad[$i] = $row["caducidad"];
    $i++;

}
mysql_close();


function nuevaPagina($pdf,$alimento,$caducidad)
{
    $pdf->AddPage(); // agregamos la pagina
    $pdf->SetMargins(12,3,0); // definimos los margenes en este caso estan en milimetros
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(223,245,222); 
    $pdf->Cell(23,8,utf8_decode("Alimento"), 1, 0, 'L','true'); 
    $pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY()); 
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9); 
    $pdf->Cell(27,8,utf8_decode($alimento),1,0,'L','true');  
    $pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY()); 
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8); 
    $pdf->Cell(13,8,utf8_decode("Caducidad"),1,0,'L','true');  
    $pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY()); 
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9); 
    $pdf->Cell(21,8,utf8_decode($caducidad),1,1,'L',true);  
}


$pdf=new PDF('P','mm','A5');


for($i=0;$i<$number-1;$i++)
{
    nuevaPagina($pdf,$alimento[$i],$caducidad[$i]);
}

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Que es fpdf.php ?

Comment: @Jorgesys un fichero de la libreria FPDF, lo saqué de un ejemplo. Sinceramente nunca había utilizado así una libreria, pero ya te digo cuando descargué la librería vi un ejemplo así. No es muy correcto verdad no?

Comment: @wiki ¿Esto es una respuesta con la solución o es el código que llevas hasta el momento y no te funciona?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es la solcuión que yo he encontrado, seguramente haya alguna mejor, la he dejado por si le sirve a alguien. Compartir es vivir!!

Comment: En `$consulta = "SELECT * FROM producto;` te faltan unas comillas `"` al final de la sentencia (justo antes del `;`).

Comment: @FranciscoRomero gracias, lo edito!!